# Ignoring NaN when interpolating grid in Python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, nan

I have a gridded velocity field that I want to interpolate in Python. Currently I'm using scipy.interpolate's `RectBivariateSpline` to do this, but I want to be able to define edges of my field by setting certain values in the grid to NaN. However, when I do this it messes up the interpolation of the entire grid, effectively making it NaN everywhere. Apparently this is an error in the scipy fitpack, so what would be the best way to work around this? I want to be able to keep the NaNs in the grid to work with edges and out of bounds later on, but I don't want it to affect the interpolation in the rest of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

All languages that implement floating point correctly (which includes python) allow you to test for a NaN by comparing a number with itself.

`x` is not equal to `x` if, and only if, `x` is NaN.

You'll be able to use that to filter your data set accordingly.

Comment: Of course, but that's not the problem. The problem is using `RectBivariateSpline` on a grid where some of the elements are allowed to be NaN. I don't want to filter out the NaNs, I want to keep them without letting them mess up the interpolation.

Comment: You'll *have* to filter them somehow. What value would you like to assume for those knots?

Answer (score 0):

Spline fitting/interpolation is global, so it's likely that even a single `nan` is messing up the whole mesh.